# How to remove click event new tab onclkds.com advertisement from chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware

In most of the website including stackoverfow.com opens a new tab on the click event (mostly first click event)  which will redirect to an advertisement. How can we remove this click event advertisement. Sometimes even Facebook too opens a new advertisement tab on click event on.

One thing I found from the source is that it includes a source from onclkds.com.

[image: StackOverflow source in chrome using Inspect Element]

Comment: You could try and download adblock, which will block pretty much any type of ad. It can be downloaded here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question so OP can mark it as solved.

You could try and download adblock, which will block pretty much any type of ad. It can be downloaded [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom):

Answer (score 0):

[chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/…](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)

Downloaded  adblock and it blocked onclkds.com advertisement.